# Help with deleting files and folders

Tags: command-line, bash

I am using Ubuntu 16.04lts, I am trying to get rid of a couple of folders.  I have tried what I thought to be the correct method, but they seem to fail.

```
$ ls -la
total 32
drwxrwxr-x 6 rod rod 4096 Aug 20 21:24 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 rod rod 4096 Aug 19 15:32 ..
drwxrwxr-x 3 rod rod 4096 Aug 20 21:24 BurnWorld.Com
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rod rod  423 Aug 20 18:48 ClickCharts Diagram Flowchart Software.desktop
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rod rod  395 Aug 21 12:16 DreamPlan Home Design Software.desktop
drwxrwxr-x 2 rod rod 4096 Aug 20 18:48 Graphics Related Programs
drwxrwxr-x 2 rod rod 4096 Aug 20 18:48 NCH Software Suite
drwxrwxr-x 2 rod rod 4096 Aug 19 15:32 Pretty Good Solitaire
$ cd /Pretty Good Solitaire
bash: cd: /Pretty: No such file or directory
$ cd /Pretty_Good_Solitaire
bash: cd: /Pretty_Good_Solitaire: No such file or directory
$ cd Pretty_Good_Solitaire
bash: cd: Pretty_Good_Solitaire: No such file or directory
```

I am trying to install wine for goodsol and everything fails so I thought I'd get rid of all traces of it, and also Wine which is needed to run it.  Then start afresh and try again.  As you see, it will not go away.

Comment: @muru: I was just about to do the same thing. :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not escaping the space character:

Type

```
rm -r ./Pretty\ Good\ Solitaire
```

Or alternatively type

```
rm -r ./Pretty
```

and then  <kbd>Tab</kbd> to use the bash [autocompletion](https://debian-administration.org/article/316/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1) feature.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783701/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-when-using-bash) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296141/how-to-use-a-special-character-as-a-normal-one) for a better understanding of escaping characters.

You are also not using the correct command, but I guess this was on purpose. Do not forget the -r flag, as otherwise rm does not delete directories. To get a comprehensive list of options:

```
man rm
```

Comment: Thank you Bruni, that did the job.  I got shot for duplicate, but the question went a little further.  I want to install Pretty Good Solitaire.  I have downloaded "Wine" , I have also downloaded i386, as the machine I'm using is 64Bit and Solitaire or wine is only 32Bit.  I have played this for years and since the box here crashed (again) I had to reinstall everything.  Yes, I had (I thought) saved a mirror of my HDD. but I am reasonably new to this Linux and at my age have trouble doing things.  However, that's life.

Comment: @RodneyJackson Glad to help. You should post a new question if you have questions that go further.